Skiasharp is not working on linux platform
I integrated SkiaSharp to generate images within my .Net 8 application . While developing the project on Windows, everything functioned correctly in the local environment. However, upon deployment to a Linux platform, the image generation functionality ceased to work as expected.
And i tried with SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux and SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies. Nothing is working.
using (var baseBitmap = new SKBitmap(width, height))
{
    baseBitmap.Erase(SKColors.White);
    using (var paint = new SKPaint())
    {
        paint.Color = SKColors.Black;


        int pixelSize = 5; // Size of each pixel
        int pixelSpacing = 1; // Spacing between pixels

        int totalWidth = captchaCode.Length * (pixelSize + pixelSpacing);

        int startX = (width - totalWidth) / 2;

        int startY = (height - pixelSize) / 2;

        using (var canvas = new SKCanvas(baseBitmap))
        {
            int x = startX;
            foreach (char c in captchaCode)
            {
                int y = startY;
                var glyphPath = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData($"{x},{y}m0,-{height}");
                canvas.DrawText(c.ToString(), x, y, paint);
                x += pixelSize + pixelSpacing;
            }
        }
    }
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    baseBitmap.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100).SaveTo(ms);
    return new CaptchaResponse { CaptchaCode = captchaCode, CaptchaByteData = ms.ToArray(), Timestamp = DateTime.Now };
}

And got the error like
The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo' threw an exception.
Please suggest on this

Please post the full error message.

Im getting only this error message
Level: Information
Time: 2024-06-24 12:18:11.465 +00:00
Message: The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo' threw an exception.
I guess in linux environment Skiasharp is not working.

Did you install both packages ?
